# Bower dependencies - resolving 'unable to find a suitable version...' message

Tags: angularjs, bower

I am trying to sort out my bower dependencies having just checkout out my repo to a different directory on my machine.

My bower.json contains the following dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular-animate": "1.5.0",
    "angular-cookies": "1.4.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.3.4",
    "angular-resource": "1.5.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.18",
    "angular": "1.5.0",
    "angular-translate": "~2.7.2",
    "angular-translate-loader-static-files": "~2.7.2",
    "angular-translate-storage-local": "~2.7.2",
    "angular-ui-validate": "~1.1.1",
    "angular-ui-router-tabs": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-material": "1.1.3",
    "angular-file-saver": "^1.1.2",
    "angular-drag-and-drop-lists": "^2.1.0",
    "angular-schema-form": "0.8.12",
    "ng-file-upload": "~9.1.1",
    "ngImgCrop": "~0.3.2",
    "ngstorage": "~0.3.9",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "lodash": "~3.9.3",
    "fontawesome": "~4.3.0",
    "json-refs": "~1.0.2",
    "sc-date-time": "~1.1.2",
    "pdfmake": "~0.1.20",
    "jszip": "2.3.0",
    "js-xlsx": "^0.8.1"
  }
```

After doing a bower install I get the following output:

```
bower cached        https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#1.4.0
bower validate      1.4.0 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cooki
es.git#1.4.0
bower cached        https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize.git#1.3.20

bower validate      1.3.20 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sani
tize.git#~1.3.4
bower cached        https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-router-bower.git#0.
2.18
bower validate      0.2.18 against https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-rout
er-bower.git#~0.2.18
bower cached        https://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate-load
er-static-files.git#2.7.2
bower validate      2.7.2 against https://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-
translate-loader-static-files.git#~2.7.2
bower cached        https://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate-stor
age-local.git#2.7.2
bower validate      2.7.2 against https://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-
translate-storage-local.git#~2.7.2
bower cached        https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-validate.git#1.1.1
bower validate      1.1.1 against https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-validate.git#
~1.1.1
bower cached        https://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate.git#
2.7.2
bower validate      2.7.2 against https://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-
translate.git#~2.7.2
bower cached        https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#1.5.0
bower validate      1.5.0 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-anima
te.git#1.5.0
bower cached        https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.5.0
bower validate      1.5.0 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1
.5.0
bower cached        https://github.com/alferov/angular-file-saver.git#1.1.3
bower validate      1.1.3 against https://github.com/alferov/angular-file-saver.
git#^1.1.2
bower cached        https://github.com/angular/bower-material.git#1.1.3
bower validate      1.1.3 against https://github.com/angular/bower-material.git#
1.1.3
bower cached        https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage.git#0.3.11
bower validate      0.3.11 against https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage.git#~0.3.
9
bower cached        https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lis
ts.git#2.1.0
bower validate      2.1.0 against https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-dra
g-and-drop-lists.git#^2.1.0
bower cached        https://github.com/rpocklin/ui-router-tabs.git#1.5.1
bower validate      1.5.1 against https://github.com/rpocklin/ui-router-tabs.git
#~1.5.0
bower cached        https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#1.5.0
bower validate      1.5.0 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resou
rce.git#1.5.0
bower cached        https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#4.3.0
bower validate      4.3.0 against https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.gi
t#~4.3.0
bower cached        https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake.git#0.1.26
bower validate      0.1.26 against https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake.git#~0.1.
20
bower cached        https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload-bower.git
#9.1.2
bower validate      9.1.2 against https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-up
load-bower.git#~9.1.1
bower cached        https://github.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop.git#0.3.2
bower validate      0.3.2 against https://github.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop.git#~0.3
.2
bower cached        https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx.git#0.8.8
bower validate      0.8.8 against https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx.git#^0.8.1
bower cached        https://github.com/moment/moment.git#2.18.1
bower validate      2.18.1 against https://github.com/moment/moment.git#^2.13.0
bower cached        https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form.git#0.8.12
bower validate      0.8.12 against https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-for
m.git#0.8.12
bower cached        https://github.com/Stuk/jszip.git#2.3.0
bower validate      2.3.0 against https://github.com/Stuk/jszip.git#2.3.0
bower cached        https://github.com/lodash/lodash.git#3.9.3
bower validate      3.9.3 against https://github.com/lodash/lodash.git#~3.9.3
bower cached        https://github.com/whitlockjc/json-refs.git#1.0.5
bower validate      1.0.5 against https://github.com/whitlockjc/json-refs.git#~1
.0.2
bower cached        https://github.com/sc-date-time/sc-date-time-dist.git#1.1.6
bower validate      1.1.6 against https://github.com/sc-date-time/sc-date-time-d
ist.git#~1.1.2
bower cached        https://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate-stor
age-cookie.git#2.7.2
bower validate      2.7.2 against https://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-
translate-storage-cookie.git#~2.7.2
bower cached        https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.14
bower validate      1.4.14 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#
>=1.2.26 <=1.5
bower cached        https://github.com/bjornstar/blob-polyfill.git#1.0.20150320
bower validate      1.0.20150320 against https://github.com/bjornstar/blob-polyf
ill.git#~1.0.20150320
bower cached        https://github.com/Teleborder/FileSaver.js.git#1.20150507.2
bower validate      1.20150507.2 against https://github.com/Teleborder/FileSaver
.js.git#~1.20150507.2
bower cached        https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.20
bower validate      1.3.20 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#
1.3.20
bower cached        https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.0
bower validate      1.4.0 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1
.4.0
bower cached        https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-aria.git#1.6.3
bower validate      1.6.3 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-aria.
git#^1.4.8
bower cached        https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-messages.git#1.6.3
bower validate      1.6.3 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-messa
ges.git#^1.4.8
bower cached        https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.git#0.13.4
bower validate      0.13.4 against https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower
.git#^0.13.0
bower cached        https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4.git#1.0.17
bower validate      1.0.17 against https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4.git#~1.0.1
5
bower cached        https://github.com/mike-marcacci/objectpath.git#1.1.0
bower validate      1.1.0 against https://github.com/mike-marcacci/objectpath.gi
t#~1.1.0
bower cached        https://github.com/davewasmer/js-traverse.git#0.6.7
bower validate      0.6.7 against https://github.com/davewasmer/js-traverse.git#
~0.6.7
bower cached        https://github.com/whitlockjc/path-loader.git#0.1.1
bower validate      0.1.1 against https://github.com/whitlockjc/path-loader.git#
~0.1.1
bower cached        https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#4.7.0
bower validate      4.7.0 against https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.gi
t#^4.2.0
bower cached        https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.6.3
bower validate      1.6.3 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1
.6.3

Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one by typing one o
f the numbers below:
    1) angular#1.3.20 which resolved to 1.3.20 and is required by angular-saniti
ze#1.3.20
    2) angular#1.4.0 which resolved to 1.4.0 and is required by angular-cookies#
1.4.0
    3) angular#^1.0.8 which resolved to 1.4.14 and is required by angular-ui-rou
ter#0.2.18
    4) angular#>= 1.0.5 which resolved to 1.4.14 and is required by angular-ui-v
alidate#1.1.1
    5) angular#>=1.0.8 which resolved to 1.4.14 and is required by ngstorage#0.3
.11
    6) angular#>=1.3.0 which resolved to 1.4.14 and is required by angular-boots
trap#0.13.4
    7) angular#^1.2.x which resolved to 1.4.14 and is required by sc-date-time#1
.1.6
    8) angular#>=1.2.26 <=1.5 which resolved to 1.4.14 and is required by angula
r-translate#2.7.2
    9) angular#^1.3.15 which resolved to 1.4.14 and is required by angular-ui-ro
uter-tabs#1.5.1
    10) angular#>1.2.0 which resolved to 1.4.14 and is required by ng-file-uploa
d#9.1.2
    11) angular#>= 1.2 which resolved to 1.4.14 and is required by angular-schem
a-form#0.8.12
    12) angular#^1.4.8 which resolved to 1.4.14 and is required by angular-mater
ial#1.1.3
    13) angular#1.5.0 which resolved to 1.5.0 and is required by angular-animate
#1.5.0, angular-resource#1.5.0, app
    14) angular#1.6.3 which resolved to 1.6.3 and is required by angular-aria#1.
6.3, angular-messages#1.6.3

Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json

? Answer
```

I want to only be using angular 1.5.0, I did install 1.6.3 a week ago on a separate branch so I guess that's why it's ended up in the bower cache.

I'm just trying to figure out what I need to do to resolve these messages.

This message in particular confuses me:

```
angular#1.6.3 which resolved to 1.6.3 and is required by angular-aria#1.
6.3, angular-messages#1.6.3
```

I haven't specified angular-aria, angular-messages, I guess it's being required by one of the other dependencies that is listed.

Any help\guidance is much appreciated!

Thanks

**UPDATE**

So I have now done a bower cache clean, and tried install again, this time it went off and downloaded everything from scratch as expected, but again gave me a choices list at the end, asking for a resolution, which included angular 1.6.3 as required by angular-aria and angular-messages.

Hunting through the bower install log output, I noticed this:

```
bower progress      tv4#~1.0.15 received 1.0MB of 1.3MB downloaded, 79%
bower progress      js-xlsx#^0.8.1 received 1.4MB of 1.6MB downloaded, 86%
bower resolved      https://github.com/angular/bower-material.git#1.1.3
bower progress      pdfmake#~0.1.20 received 1.8MB of 4.1MB downloaded, 43%
bower not-cached    https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-aria.git#^1.4.8
bower resolve       https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-aria.git#^1.4.8
bower not-cached    https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-messages.git#^1.4.8

bower resolve       https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-messages.git#^1.4.8

bower progress      tv4#~1.0.15 received 1.1MB of 1.3MB downloaded, 83%
bower progress      js-xlsx#^0.8.1 received 1.5MB of 1.6MB downloaded, 93%
bower progress      pdfmake#~0.1.20 received 1.9MB of 4.1MB downloaded, 46%
bower progress      tv4#~1.0.15 received 1.1MB of 1.3MB downloaded, 88%
bower progress      fontawesome#~4.3.0 received 0.6MB of 2.2MB downloaded, 27%
bower progress      pdfmake#~0.1.20 received 2.0MB of 4.1MB downloaded, 47%
bower progress      js-xlsx#^0.8.1 received 1.6MB of 1.6MB downloaded, 99%
bower progress      tv4#~1.0.15 received 1.2MB of 1.3MB downloaded, 90%
bower extract       js-xlsx#^0.8.1 archive.tar.gz
bower progress      fontawesome#~4.3.0 received 0.7MB of 2.2MB downloaded, 31%
bower retry         Download of https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/arch
ive/v4.7.0.tar.gz failed with ESOCKETTIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.9s
bower progress      pdfmake#~0.1.20 received 2.0MB of 4.1MB downloaded, 48%
bower progress      tv4#~1.0.15 received 1.2MB of 1.3MB downloaded, 95%
bower invalid-meta  for:C:\Users\rparker\AppData\Local\Temp\ACT-rparker\bower\8d
63ef64e2b12f5b0d8616fa7e1b8597-33748-TEeBQh\bower.json
bower invalid-meta  The "main" field cannot contain minified files
bower download      https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-messages/archive/v1
.6.3.tar.gz
bower progress      pdfmake#~0.1.20 received 2.0MB of 4.1MB downloaded, 48%
bower progress      fontawesome#~4.3.0 received 0.7MB of 2.2MB downloaded, 32%
bower download      https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-aria/archive/v1.6.3
.tar.gz
bower resolved      https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx.git#0.8.8
bower progress      tv4#~1.0.15 received 1.3MB of 1.3MB downloaded, 99%
bower progress      fontawesome#~4.3.0 received 0.8MB of 2.2MB downloaded, 35%
bower extract       tv4#~1.0.15 archive.tar.gz
bower progress      pdfmake#~0.1.20 received 2.0MB of 4.1MB downloaded, 49%
bower extract       angular-messages#^1.4.8 archive.tar.gz
bower resolved      https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-messages.git#1.6.3
bower not-cached    https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.6.3
bower resolve       https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.6.3
```

The angular-messages and angular-aria packages seem to download around the time angular-material is being resolved. Looking in the bower.json for the angular-material library I can see angular-messages and angular-aria are listed as dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "angular-material",
  "version": "1.1.3-master-0f3ef64",
  "license": "MIT",
  "ignore": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.4.8",
    "angular-animate": "^1.4.8",
    "angular-aria": "^1.4.8",
    "angular-messages": "^1.4.8"
  },
  "main": [
    "angular-material.js",
    "angular-material.css"
  ]
}
```

But angular 1.5.0 has already been fetched for me earlier in the log from what I can tell, so I'm wondering why 1.6.3. get's fetched as I would have thought that 1.5.0 would fulfill the ^1.4.8 version defined in the above angular-material bower.json.

Comment: Try to clean your cache ? and look out for ng aria and ng message versions that can run on Angular 1.5.0 if needed..

Comment: Thanks @DevMoutarde - I gave this a go, see my latest update on my original question. I'm still getting the same behaviour

Comment: Can you try using resolutions ? following this : { "resolutions": {  "angular": ~1.3.0"  }} ; so it should download dependencies using a specific version of Angular. More here https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/How-to-use-a-different-version-of-AngularJS-using-Bower